# Facebook API Album Images random slider

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api

I am looking for help

I have code that I found and trying to tweek. It works but gets the images from an album which there are 26 at this moment. I want to only get 11 at random and add to the div. If you can help that would be great. I tried to add history so that the index wont be used at least in the same displayed 11 photos. If anyone can help clean it up functionally too that would be great. I am doing this free for my nieces that got killed in a car accident.

http://jsfiddle.net/ad5qa/2JjbV/

```
$.fn.fbPhotos = function (album, limit) {

    function base_append(obj) {
            $(base).append(obj);
    }

    function getPhoto(obj) {

            var id = obj.id;
            var img = obj.img;
            var link = obj.link;


            var wrap = $('<div></div>').attr({
                    'class': 'fb-photo',
                    'id': id
            });


            var avatar = new Image();
            avatar.src = img;

            var _avatar = $('<a></a>').attr('href', link).attr('target', '_blank').attr('class', 'avatar').html(avatar);

            $(wrap).append($(_avatar));
            return wrap;

    }

    function init() {
            fetch();

    }



    function fetch() {
            var r;
            var data = {};

            $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + albumId + '/photos?type=small&limit=' + topLimit,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (obj) {
                            //    console.log(obj);
                            if (obj.error) {
                                    /*       var img = new Image();
                                 img.src = theme_url + '/images/ico_fail_bird.png';
                                 wipe(img); */
                                    return false;
                            } else {

                                    var results = {};


                                    for (var k = 0; k < obj.data.length; k++) {
                                            if (obj.data[k].images) {
                                                    results[k] = {
                                                            'id': obj.data[k].id,
                                                            'img': obj.data[k].images[8].source,
                                                            'link': obj.data[k].link
                                                    };
                                            }
                                    }

                                    k = 0;
                                    var hist = [];
                                    for (var w = 0; w < 11; w++) {
                                            var rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * obj.data.length - 1) + 1);
                                            if ($.inArray(rnd, hist) == -1) {
                                                    hist.push(rnd);
                                                    $('.vcard').append(rnd + ' - ');
                                                    base_append(getPhoto(results[rnd]));
                                                    k++;
                                                    if (k >= topLimit) {
                                                            break;
                                                    }
                                            }

                                    }



                                    if (hist.length > obj.data.length - 2) hist = null;

                                    (function showNext(jq) {
                                            jq.eq(0).show("slide", null, 100, function () {
                                                    (jq = jq.slice(1)).length && showNext(jq);
                                            });
                                    })($('div.fb-photo'));

                                    return true;
                            }
                    },
                    error: function (obj) {
                            // @todo: do something like append an error message or an error image
                            /*  var img = new Image();
                        img.src = '/images/fail.png';
                        wipe(img); */
                            return false;
                    }
            });



    }

    if ($(this).size() > 0) {
            var base = $(this);
            var topLimit = (limit ? limit : 50);
            var albumId = (album ? album : ($(this).attr("fbAlbum") ? $(this).attr("fbAlbum") : '0'));

            init();
    }

};


$(".block-facebook").fbPhotos();
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
            $(".block-facebook").fbPhotos();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: try http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/ . sorry for your loss

Comment: thanks much. Will browse around that site as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `topLimit` before its initialized. Besides that, you need to get all URLs for all pictures and than just select some of them randomly inside the return array.

Answer (score 0):

Resulted in practically writing my own, for now it will work. Implemented fancybox as well. Been years since messing with json and javascript/livescript.

```
    function getthumbs(gallery_id) {
        viewer = $('#viewer'), thumbs = $('#thumbs');
        var hist = [];
        var rnd = 0;

        $.getJSON('//graph.facebook.com/' + gallery_id + '/photos?callback=?', function (json, status, xhr) {
            var imgs = json.data;
            $('#thumbs img').remove();

            for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * imgs.length - 1) + 1);

                $('<img src="' + imgs[rnd].images[8].source + '">').appendTo(thumbs).fancybox({
                    href: imgs[rnd].images[3].source
                }); 
            }

        });
    }
    getthumbs('425912634133232');

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            getthumbs('425912634133232');
        }, 20000);
    });
```